# render() versus Knit GUI for word_document

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to knit a table created by `kable()` and produce a Word document. When I knit using the RStudio knit button, it works fine and produces a formatted table. When I use `render()`, it does not. It produces just a unformatted string of text.  Here is a minimal example:

test.Rmd

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  word_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(mtcars)
```
````

The `render()` command is

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", clean=FALSE)
```

The `pandoc` command that is run by both the Knit button (RStudio) and the `render()` command is

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.docx --smart --highlight-style tango
```

I can see the problem in the `test.utf8.md` file produced by `pandoc()` when I run `render()`.  The `test.utf8.md` file is an html table. I cannot see the `test.utf8.md` file produced by clicking the Knit button since that is not saved with `keep_md=true`. Only the `test.md` file is kept.

Answer (score 0):

The RStudio Knit button must be changing the `kable()` format when output is `word_document`.  If I change the `kable()` call to

```
knitr::kable(mtcars, format="markdown")
```

It works. The following sets the `kable()` format. I don't know what output format the user will select, so don't want to set format in the function call. Putting this with an if statement to detect if the output type is Word, fixes the problem.

```
options(knitr.table.format = 'markdown')
```